# How can I hide a div completely from HTML DOM?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs in my page, each div have class a , b.
I also have 2 urls

- www.site.com/a
- www.site.com/b

**Goal** : I want to hide `div` with class `b` when I'm at site/a
and vice of versa.

The goal is to hide them completely from the DOM. 
I'm not sure how to do that.

I've tried

**JS**

```
var lastSegment = location.pathname.split('/').pop();

if (lastSegment === 'a') {

    $(".a").removeClass("hidden");

} else {

    $(".b").removeClass("hidden");

}
```

**CSS**

```
.hidden {
  display: none!important;
  visibility: hidden!important;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="a hidden"> // Logic </div>
<div class="b hidden"> // Logic </div>
```

**Result**

I can see both of the div when I do inspect element.

Any helps / hints / suggestions on this will be much appreciated

Comment: if you're already using jQuery it's probably easiest to just use `$(.a).hide()`, and not manipulate classes and css manually.

Comment: If you don't want the div in the DOM, then why do you have it in the markup?

Comment: do you run the js after document load?

Comment: @Amit : I want to be able to hide/show them base on the URL.

Comment: if you are not running the js do you still see both?

Comment: Are you using a static server? If you have any kind of processing functionality, get rid of it at the server. If you don't, life is much better.. have 2 static files!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/detach/

Comment: Please note that if you sent html to the client, and then remove it using javascript, a malicious user can still intercept the original html (turn off javascript, just use curl instead). Better is, like said before, to just not send it to the client (browser).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

jQuery's [.detach()](https://api.jquery.com/detach/) is doing this.

> The .detach() method is the same as .remove(), except that .detach()
>   keeps all jQuery data associated with the removed elements. This
>   method is useful when removed elements are to be reinserted into the
>   DOM at a later time.

Answer (score 2):

Here:

```
   var lastSegment = location.pathname.split('/').pop();

    if (lastSegment === 'a') {
        $(".b").remove();
    } else {
        $(".a").remove();
    }
```

You can use remove() function to remove it completely.

Comment: Really, can we do that. That'll be awesome if it works.

Comment: Damn, dude, you save my life. This is working !! Confirm !!.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot get rid on the DOM by adding and removing classes. There are multiple ways you can tackle this .

1. Add/Remove divs using Javascript completely. Don't render both.

   ```
   if(lastSegment === "a") {
     $(".target").append('<div class="a">Link A</div>');
   } 
   else {
    $(".target").append('<div class="a">Link B</div>');
   }
   ```
2. Use Shadow DOM - ShadowDom elements are not visible with inspect element, unless making some settings buried deep inside setting icons.

Tutorial : http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/shadowdom/
Thanks

Comment: I don't really get your answer. Can you tell me more on this "Add/Remove divs using Javascript completely. Don't render both." ?

Comment: Your second one is lost me completely.

Comment: Thanks for editing it. I like the `append` idea that you're suggesting. :)

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

```
if (lastSegment === 'a') {

    $(".a").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".b").addClass("hidden");

} else {

    $(".a").addClass("hidden");
    $(".b").removeClass("hidden");


}
```

Comment: So you suggested, I should add class `hidden` as I go base on the url, right.

Comment: Will this remove from the DOM ?

Comment: No this will not remove form DOM. Need to use .remove() method to remove it